# Can I attach a \footnote to a \sidepar

Tags: formatting, notes

Sorry for the sloppy question and editing: here my connection comes and goes in the afternoon.

In a few word I need the footnote attached to a sidepar to be treated together with all the other footnotes attached to the main text.

I need something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\settrimmedsize{340mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{46.7mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{54.9mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{2.8mm}{23.3mm}{1em}
\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont‌​\small}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont‌​\small}
\sideparmargin{outer}


\checkandfixthelayout



\begin{document}

A normal paragraph begins here,\sidepar{This is my Sidepar. \footnote{This is a footnote, but it appears as a sidepar footnote, if I may say so.}} it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and onand on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and onand on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and onand on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on,\footnote{This is how my footnote should appear.} and finally it ends here. 

\end{document}
```

Thank you,
A

---

Following Jon's advice I made this, but it gives problems with numeration of footnotes (all notes at the foot are numbered 3).

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}             
\begin{document} 

\sidepar{Lorem ipsum,\footnotemark Lorem ipsum,\footnotemark Lorem ipsum.\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{Text for note 1} \footnotetext{Text for note 2} \footnotetext{Text for note 3}% 
\lipsum                                              

\end{document}
```

Thank you,

A

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `footnote` package is designed to help with such situations.  Place the `\sidenote` in a `savenotes` environment, and the footnotes will be collected up and printed after the environment:

[image: Sampel output]

```
\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document} 

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{Text for note 1}\lipsum[2]
\begin{savenotes}
  \sidepar{Lorem ipsum,\footnote{Text for note 2} Lorem
  ipsum,\footnote{Text for note 3} Lorem
  ipsum.\footnote{Text for note 4}}
\end{savenotes}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{Text for note 5} \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}             
\begin{document} 

\sidepar{Lorem ipsum\footnotemark}%
\footnotetext{\lipsum*[1]}% 
\lipsum                                              

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Jon and Christian, sorry for my sloppy questino and my partial editing: yesterday afternoon our internet connection was coming and going and finally it left us offline. I edited my question. Thank you. A